# Error when creating a search service application in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I'm migrating a SharePoint 2010 environment to 2013.  The 2010 environment is fairly simple as it only contains documents.  However, after I migrated all the content and service application databases.  I tried to create a Search Service Application using both CA and PowerShell.

Both times I received the following error:

> Could not find stored procedure dbo.prc_TenantLog_CreateTVFs

I tried searching the old SharePoint 2010 databases and was unable to locate the stored proc anywhere. I tried searching the internet and could not find anyone with the same issue.  Is there a CU update that I need to install?

Hope someone can help

Comment: check this document http://akforsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/10/migrate-sharepoint-2010-search-service.html

Comment: I tried this already when I created the Search Service using PowerShell.  When I ran the PowerShell command to create the service is when the error message pops up.

Comment: Ok.is it fast 2010 or sp 2010 search service?

Comment: No it's SP 2010 Search Service

Comment: I could create the stored procedure manually if I knew what the Transact-SQL was.

Comment: No, this will totally put u in unsupported mode.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the answer to another forum and included the link below.  But it seems to be working now

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c9d7c2fe-9611-4040-8d0d-afc08a241e08/error-when-creating-a-search-service-application-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointadmin